# How to vertically move a block containing fixed and absolute elements

Tags: css

Everything is in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brFsB/1/).
I would like to be able to move up/down the div `.global-wrapper`. I tried to set up many different combinations with `fixed` and `absolute` positions on 2 containers, but i can't make it work without unstructuring the containing elements during the transition.

A solution could be to move up/down the 3 elements `.top` `.middle` and `.bottom` using JavaScript, but i would prefer to move them in a "single process" if it's possible.

**HTML**

```
<div class="global-wrapper">
    <div class="global-container">
        <div class="top">TOP</div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="content">MIDDLE</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.global-wrapper { height: 500px; width: 700px; position: absolute; top: 0%; }
.global-wrapper .global-container { height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; }
.global-wrapper .global-container .top { height: 20%; width: 100%; background-color:blue; position: fixed; top: 0px; }
.global-wrapper .global-container .middle { height: 60%; width: 500%; overflow: hidden; background-color:green; position: absolute; top: 20%; }
.global-wrapper .global-container .middle .content { height: 100%; width: 100%; position relative; }
.global-wrapper .global-container .bottom { height: 20%; width: 100%; background-color:blue; position: fixed; bottom: 0%; }
```

**Update:**

This structure deserves some explanations, it's in fact a simple page with 2 navbar (one at the top and one at the bottom) in fixed position, and a slide in the middle (that's why the `.middle div` is larger than its parents).

I would like to be able to moove the whole structure up and down (when clicking a button but it doesn't matter here), in order to hide a part of it behind the window (for example, if i set up `top: -15%` to the `.global-wrapper div`, i expect the whole structure to be 15% hidden behind the top browser window).

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: It's really unclear what are you trying to do

Comment: what do you mean by "moving up/down" while scrolling ?

Comment: @Itay Yes it seems weird but it's very simple: a fixed navbar at the top, another one at the bottom, and a kind of carousel in the middle, i would like to be able to moove up/down the whole block

Comment: Move it where and relative to what?

Comment: moving the entire thing up/down, whilst  simultaneously having 2 navbars in a fixed position, is somewhat of an oxymoron...

Comment: @caramba Not scrolling, but when clicking a button or any other action, i would like to be able to moove the whole block

Comment: @Itay relative to the body, i want to moove it up, in order to hide a part of it of the window, and moove it down, in order to initialize its position

Comment: Are you talking about a sliding menu? which move the div down when opened?

Comment: @user1641165 It's more complexe, it's like a menu containing a slider in the middle, and 2 fixed elements around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're looking for something like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/brFsB/8/)**

```
.global-wrapper .global-container:hover {
    transform:translatey(-150%);
    transition: all 3s;
}
.global-wrapper .global-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 3s;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the effect: 
`.global-wrapper .global-container {
    transform: translatey(-150%);
    transition: all 3s;
}`
but you brang the key, thanks !

Comment: @Ludo that was my first move, but it seemed odd that you would be wanting to do it that way, so I thought it was a miscommunication and I moved the transform to the middle div... Sorry about that, edited to correct

Comment: I realize that my working case wasn't easy to understand and you have been very hopefull to me ! Didn't think 1 second about a `transfom` property when playing with the `positions` ones... Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You are contradicting yourself with the different classes. A fixed class is a fixed class. I would recommend that you remove all positioning from your content divs for the second and simply use the parent container.

Changing a the parent div of a fixed div wont move the fixed container. You will also notice that the green middle div is moving. This one does not have fixed positioning.

I hope that helps.

Comment: If i do that, i won't be able to slide `.middle .content` on the left and right without mooving the top bars (on left/right), i want to keep them fit the whole screen `width`, even when sliding the `.middle .content` so if i am not wrong `position: fixed` is the tool for it.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no way to move a fixed div -15%. I'm sure there are other solutions but I'm not quite sure why you would want to hide some of your website.

Comment: Not sure where we're going with this but maybe one hack of a solution may be to stick another div overtop of the bit you don't want to show with a higher z-index. It's nasty but it solves your issue quickly